# Model as One to One or One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, normalization, database-normalization

I have a table `foo`. In `foo` there are 4 columns: `id`, `barTypeA`, `barTypeB`, `barTypeC`. The only candidate key is the `id`. `barTypeA`, `B`, `C` are all non-prime attributes. The attributes are technically not just a list; the fact that a `bar` is of type A, B or C is not trivial. However, `barTypeA`, `B` and `C` are nullable.

I could make this table into three tables (eg `foo`, `fooToBar` and `barType`) with a one-to-many relationship from `foo` to `fooToBar`, but I am curious as to if/how the original design violates a database design standard or normal form.

Comment: I think it is interesting -- if this was not abstract, say a class information with 150 columns for each potential student id you would be quick to see why that is a bad design.  For some reason because this is only 3 items you feel your design is OK

Comment: My 2 cents: If your system is not expected to ever contain more bar types, then keep the original design. There is such a thing as over-normalized.

Comment: I think that @ZoharPeled is exactly right, if something is implemented and is working there might not be a reason to change it -- on the other hand normalization rules and techniques exist for a reason....

Comment: @ZoharPeled the issue with that is that you are just asking for someone to need more bar types.  Every time a developer on my team tempts the fates like that it happens

Comment: @marshall: Murphy will never die... I'm a strong believer of evolution of software. If it's only 3 column that may perhaps need to be converted to a normalized structure some time in the far future, then i see no reason to normalize in the present. **However**, if it's a likely thing to happen then by all means start with a normalized system.

Comment: Thanks for all the feed back everyone. I'm thinking that the solution is to go with a single table because that is what others on the team are agreeing on. It was a hotly contested subject for awhile. Although @Hogan had a really good point in his first point. I'll update once the design was finally decided upon.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you only need a join table (`fooToBar`) if you have many-to-many relationships. In one-to-one and one-to-many, the id of the one (`foo`) is referenced by entries in the many (`bar`).

In other words, if each entry in `bar` is only ever connected to one `foo` entry, then `bar` should just reference `foo.id`. But if a `bar` can be linked to several `foo`s and a `foo` can be linked to several `bar`s, *then* use a `fooToBar` join table.

Comment: While true, I'm not sure that's what the OP is asking about.